# SSL / TLS on EC2 load balancer - why does it work?

Tags: ssl, https, amazon-ec2, tls, load-balancer

My boss says to get SSL / TLS working on EC2 servers, just put a load balancer in front of them that uses https. But I can still access the original servers with http. So is this really secure? Doesn't seem like to me. I would assume the original servers would only need to serve https only too?

Answer (score 2):

Alter the *Security Group* (firewall) protecting the original servers so that they don't accept HTTP from the Internet.

Comment: got it, so we can still ssh into the original servers, but no http..or rather they only do http with the load balancer in the intranet